# HTML reference in bib file

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, bibtex

I am sure you have encountered with the following question, so in advance I would be thankful to your help.

I have created a bib file, and one of the my reference is an article on the web which I would like it to make a hyperlink reference, i.e I want to be shown in the way that if I click on it, it goes to the web page.

Comment: And where is the question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully. However, as you appear to be using hyperref, why don't you provide a *note*  or *url* field (or whatever field type is most appropriate for your bibliographic entry) that contains something like

```
"Available online at \url{http://www.mysite.mycountry/xyz.html}"
```

or, if you want to to use the `\href` command,

```
"Available online at \href{http://www.mysite.mycountry/xyz.html}{this site}"
```

**Addendum**: Please note that this solution works with both `bibtex` and `biblatex`. However, far more elegant solutions are available with biblatex. See for instance, on pp.8 f. of the [biblatex manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), a discussion of the entry type `online`, "intended for sources such as web sites which are intrinsicly online resources." Also, all biblatex entry types support the field `url`.

Comment: `biblatex` has features to generate text for qualifying URLs, though I'm not certain the `biblatex` tag was applied correctly here...

Comment: @Audrey: I don't think that my answer applies only to `biblatex`. For BibTeX entries of the `@unpublished` type, for instance, most .bst files will print out the contents of the `note` field, right? In addition, many *modern* .bst files (such as those that come with the `natbib` package) recognize the `url` field and will print out its contents. I'll add the tag `bibtex` to the question.

Comment: That was my point - this answer wouldn't be a good one for `biblatex`. The OP applied the `biblatex` tag, but they may have just mixed it up with `bibtex`.

Comment: @Audrey -- thanks for the follow-up, I now get your point. By the way, my answer mentions a field of type `url`, so I don't think it's not a "good answer" for users of `biblatex`... For what it's worth, I had actually assumed all along that the `biblatex` tag didn't mean that it applied *only* to `biblatex`...

Comment: @MIco: Can you add that this solution isn't `biblatex` like.

Comment: @Marco: Are you OK with the addendum? Please advise.

Comment: @MIco: Very nice ;-)